# How to delete invisible photos and videos from iPad?

Tags: photos, ios, storage

MF519LL/A, iOS 8.1.3

General -> About -> Photos = 700 photos

General -> Usage -> Manage Storage -> Photos & Camera = 900 MB

Open Photos app. No photos or videos in any folder (Photos and Albums).

How to clear cache or whatever to free my 900 MB?

Answer (score 1):

Restore it by connecting to a computer with iTunes.  That will fix it.

Comment: I don't have a computer with iTunes. I don't want to restore them. I want free space they are using.